# TFS 2015 RC BuildvNext - Builds stop after Get Sources

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I just loaded a new instance of the TFS 2015 RC and encountered the new build system. I see that MS is positioning it as the new default build system so I am working on recreating my existing XAML builds. I am coming up short, though.

The first 2 runs of my build continued past the Get Sources step but there were errors in the build. After resolving that, my builds now stop after the 'Get Sources' step. There is no error message. My next build step just says 'Not started'.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question so that this may help someone else in the future.

The problem was caused by the default build agent that TFS created. After deleting the default build agent and recreating it, my builds now work exactly as I would expect. Hopefully this is just an issue with RC and will be fixed before RTM.

Comment: Next time you see this, look in the _diag folder for traces.  you can also send to me or my team